# Google Analytics inside IFRAME for shared HTML document

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I have a bunch of HTML pages on my web site. Each HTML page uses an IFRAME to display a single common HTML footer page. Instead of having to put the google analytics code in every HTML page, I would like to put it in the common footer page and have it log the vists to every parent (containing) page independently. From the analytics report I whould be able to identify the parent HTML page that was visited. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can `appendChild()` a `<script>` block to `top.document.head`.